# Order integral and derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I am having trouble with this question! i Was able to list the integrals from smallest to largest, but I am having trouble listing the derivatives.

As of now I have b < c < d < a[image: prompt]

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Mario

Comment: The derivative is just the slope of the graph.  At $2.5$, the derivative appears to be near zero, whereas it is negative at $5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm just a little more confused about the sign issue, so if I get this right if something is negative, then it's smaller than the positive ones. But does that apply to the integrals as well? Like does the area between 6 and 9 (integral between 6 and 9) become smaller than the other ones because it's negative (under the x axis)? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that applies to the integrals as well.  The integral between $6$ and $9$ is negative, so it will be less than all the other integrals listed.  This is what the comment "Be careful with your signs!" is getting at.

Comment: Thanks so much @greelious it's much clearer now!